# How do I hide a WPF DataGrid Column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I created a DataGrid using XAML like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GroupVw" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HeadersVisibility="None" Height="196" />
```

I have behind code that looks like this:

```
public static string ConnStr { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            ConnStr = @"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\LakDb_YIX6R.mdf;Integrated security=True;Connection Timeout=30";

            InitializeComponent();
            GetGroups();
        }

        public void GetGroups()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable gTbl = new DataTable();

                using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
                {
                    string query = "select * from Groups";
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, c))
                    {
                        c.Open();
                        da.Fill(gTbl);
                        c.Close();
                    }
                }

                GroupVw.ItemsSource = gTbl.DefaultView;
                GroupVw.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Lock & Key", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
```

and when I run the program I get an error message saying "index out of range." and the DataGrid is filled with 2 columns. The first column is the Id number and the second is the group name. What I would like is to hide the first column from the user but allow it accessible to the program.

Is that possible? How do I do it?

I tried replacing the behind code line:

```
GroupVw.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

with:

```
int n = GroupVw.Columns.Count;
MessageBox.Show("Column Count: " + n.ToString());
```

and when I run the program I get a message box displaying: "Column count: 0"

So how is this possible when I see data in the DataGrid and how can I fix it?

Also, how can I hide the one column?

Answer (score 0):

I think since your `DataGrid` columns are automatically generated, you could try subscribing to the [`DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn) event and hiding columns there. Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GroupVw" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HeadersVisibility="None" Height="196" AutoGeneratingColumn="GroupVw_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

Event handler:

```
private void GroupVw_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Id")
    {
        e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it takes some time to generate your columns.

Since you only seem to want one then I would consider setting autogeneratecolumns false on the datagrid and explicitly defining the one column you want. I'd will still be there in the datacontext of your row.

It seems rather strange you're using a datagrid at all though. For just one column. maybe this should be a listbox.

Alternatively, you could handle contentrendered on the window. This will fire after the datagrid builds out it's columns. You can then do

```
 GroupVw.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```